# Why am I not able to destructure "user" in my component that I have created in context? Am I missing Something?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I also want to know if I can destructure children the way I did or do I have to pass props then say "props.children"

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const UserContext = createContext();

export const UserContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(true);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider values={{ user, setUser }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

I have also wrapped the App component by "UserContextProvider"

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "../../context/userContext";

export const Main = () => {
  const { user } = useContext(UserContext);

  return (
    <main>
      <div className="main__postButton">
        {user ? () : ()}
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};
```

I am getting the following error.

```
Cannot destructure property 'user' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined.
```

Comment: You have a typo: `values=` should be `value=`

Comment: the one above and did you actually put `UserContextProvider` in the tree?

Comment: Thank you @NicholasTower. That was so silly.

Comment: @JulianKleine Yes I did, it works fine now.